# How to give input in Python MySQL LIKE Query?

Tags: python, mysql

I am New in python and I tried to connect MySQL with Python using MySQLdb module.

Here comes Pain for me. I am trying to give input in MySQL Query in python. 
My code is following:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import pandas as pd
import json
#from bson import json_util

cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost',
                             database = 'cb-dev',
                             user = 'root',
                             password = 'root', 
                             compress = 1,
                             cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
# Python Dictionary 
d= {"Date": "2017-09-26","Title": "software","Location1": "USA","Location2": "United States",
    "Location3": "United States of America","Competency_user": "App\\Job","Comp1_ID": 482,"Comp2_ID": 483,
    "Comp3_ID": 484,"Day_rate_lower": 300,"Day_rate_upper": 500,"hourly_rate_lower": 30,"hourly_rate_upper": 50
}

# Query for Sorting Data from Database and get job ID wich are suitable to talent profile
query3 = """SELECT id FROM   jobs WHERE  Date(jobs.closing_date) >= %(Date)s 
    AND title LIKE %(Title)s
       AND ( location_name_list LIKE %(Location1)s
              OR location_name_list LIKE %(Location2)s
              OR location_name_list LIKE  %(Location3)s) 
       AND ( EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM   competencies 
                            INNER JOIN competency_maps 
                                    ON competencies.id = 
                                       competency_maps.competency_id 
                     WHERE  jobs.id = 
                            competency_maps.competency_mappable_id 
                            AND competency_maps.competency_mappable_type = %(Competency_user)s 
                            AND competency_id IN ( %(Comp1_ID)s, %(Comp2_ID)s, %(Comp3_ID)s )) 
              OR ( job_rate BETWEEN %(Day_rate_lower)s AND %(Day_rate_upper)s 
                   AND job_type = "day rate" ) 
              OR ( job_rate BETWEEN %(hourly_rate_lower)s AND %(hourly_rate_upper)s
                   AND job_type = "contract rate" ))"""

print(query3)
cursor = cnx.cursor()


cursor.execute(query3,d)
print (cursor._last_executed)
sorted_job_Id = cursor.fetchall()
```

When I Run this code it is not give me any Result but when I tried to input manually each place same input it gives me result below:

`({'id': 47467},)`

I tried to do googling tried to refer past stackflow questions but I have not got correct answers.

it mostly showing me below error:

`ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string`

I tried to print Query with parameters from below statment:

`print (cursor._last_executed)`

Problem is its not taking "%" sign when LIKE query comes because whenever I Do manually with "%". it Runs and give me Desire Output.

So Now can anyone please tell me How to give placeholder or Run LIKE SQL query in python?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for Comment

I tried your suggestion `LIKE (%(Location1)s || '%%')` but its not working and still give me same error

I tried also concatenate string with "%" using
`"%"+"%(Location1)s"+"%"` it also not working

Comment: Don't add them around the placeholder, but the *value* that you're passing.

Comment: ( stackoverflow.com/questions/2097475/….) answer in this Question also not working `"%s%%"` . Give me same error

Comment: @IljaEverilä without placeholder Also not working same Error. Too much frustrating now

Comment: Try and step back for a bit. Do something else entirely. Then retry, but with the most simple example you can think of first, and proceed from there. The linked posts should provide you with all you need, but perhaps you've just been at it for so long now that everything just seems like a mess. Btw I forgot that MySQL does not use `||` for string concatenation, but `CONCAT()`, so it's `CONCAT(%(Location1)s, '%%')` instead.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for comment